# HTML Form Slider Group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, slider

I'm in need of a Slider Group, or something equivalent (I'm unsure of an official name).

Essentially, there's multiple sliders, and they all add up to 100%. By increasing one, you decrease the others.

I know that this problem has been solved already, as I've seen it used over at Humble Bundle, where you select where your donations go. Is there a library out there that does this?

If not, I'm fine with building something using jQuery-UI, or some other UI framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI sliders to do this pretty easily. Below is some pseudo code of the javascript you'll want to look into. The documentation does a pretty good job of covering how the events work:

API Documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b54dntrz/

HTML:

```
    <div id="slider1"></div>
    <br/>
    <div id="slider2"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slider1').slider({ 
        max: 100,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            var slider2val = $('#slider2').slider('value');
            if (ui.value + slider2val > 100) {
                $('#slider2').slider({
                    value: slider2val - 1

                });
            }
        }
    });
    $('#slider2').slider({
        max: 100,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            var slider1val = $('#slider1').slider('value');
            if (ui.value + slider1val > 100) {
                $('#slider1').slider({
                    value: slider1val - 1
                });
            }
        },
    });

})
```

Comment: This doesn't work when a slider is moved left. All of the other sliders should be moved right to keep their collective sum at 100%. Also, this needs to work for an arbitrary number of sliders.